# Аргументы и ключи программы

Tags: c++, параметры

У многих программ есть параметры, которые мы указываем при запуске, например

```
ls -lah
```

Эти параметры, насколько я понимаю, делятся на ключи и аргументы(Ключи с дефисом впереди и их можно объединять, а аргументы строго через пробел)

```
rm -r ./dir
```

Выходит, что -r ключ,а ./dir аргумент. На основе этого вопрос. Неужели каждая программа(скрипт), принимает ключи в условный `main(int argc, char *argv[])` и потом каждый программист отдельно пишет обработчик ключей, чтобы они могли указываться вместе, или через дефис по отдельности ещё и в разном порядке? Мне кажется нет. В связи с этим вопрос, какая общепринятая практика существует для этого и как в программу(для примера на С++) правильно принять ключи?

Comment: См., например, [`getopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

Comment: в обработке ключей ничего сложного нет. группировка ключей в стиле юникс - это не стандарт (также как и наименования), в винде такая штука не поддерживается. да и поддержать группировку ничего сложного нет. не вижу смысла использовать сторонние библиотеки для такой простой задачи.

Comment: [boost.program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/program_options.html) , но есть и другие библиотеки.

Comment: В `qt` есть [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcommandlineparser.html)

Comment: Еще: https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11